# Export to csv: one line splitted in two

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

I'm trying to export some "dossiers" (in my case) to a CSV file with jasper reports. Everything goes well but from time to time jasper reports seems to split 1 line into 2.

Example:

```
1: 2561, 35013, 20140604, 20140604, , , , , , , , , , , 2731501, 2731501, LP, A, , , , , 2014, false
2: 2563, 35013, 20140505, 20140604, , , , , , , , , , , 2731501, 2731501, AQ, F, , , , , 2014, false
3: 25, , 20, 20, , , , , , , , , , , 27, 27, ZZ, C, , , , , 20, fal
4: 65, , 140604, 140604, , , , , , , , , , , 31501, 31501, , , , , , , 14, se
5: 2568, 35013, 20140505, 20140604, , , , , , , , , , , 2731501, 2731501, AQ, , , , , , 2014, false
```

as you can see line 1 2 and 5 are correct. Line 3 and 4 are split in 2 lines but they should be one. Anyone here has got the same problem and a possible solution?

I've already duplicated the record from the database and exported again and then everything is as it should.

Comment: Are you talking about using of *JRCsvExporter*? What version of *JR* library are you using?

Comment: It's indeed the JRCsvExporter. But it's fixed. noticed that it happend every 16th line and it seems that was the place where JR put a new page. Set the "ignore pagination" property to true and it was fixed.

Comment: You can post this solution as the answer to help SO readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @GregD

It's indeed the *JRCsvExporter*. But it's fixed: noticed that it happend every 16th line and it seems that was the place where JR put a new page. Set the *"ignore pagination"* property to true and it was fixed.